# How can I add a new field in Datastudio that refer to the value in another field on an earlier date

Tags: looker-studio

I have the following table:

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1/2/2018 | 5 |
| 1/3/2018 | 7 |
| 1/4/2018 | 2 |
| 1/5/2018 | 13 |

I want to add a new field (Value1) with the help of a formula in Google Datastudio, that contains the Value field from the previous date, and another field (Value2) that contains the Value field from 2 days earlier.

| Date | Value | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/2/2018 | 5 |  |  |
| 1/3/2018 | 7 | 5 |  |
| 1/4/2018 | 2 | 7 | 5 |
| 1/5/2018 | 13 | 2 | 7 |

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Given that the date is in the column `day` and formated as date not datetime. Please add fields like `day-1` and `day-2` with the formula

```
date(datetime_add(day,interval 1 day))
```

Under the menu Resources choose Managle blends.
Blend the source with itself:
[image]

To use these fields in calculation, a formula can be added in the metrics:
[image]

Comment: I need it to be in a formula

Comment: In a blend dataset no additional fields can be added. However, adding a formula in graph/table is possible.

Comment: So, I don't want to use a blended dataset. I want to create a field that do the same with a formula.