# Deducting two tables to show combined 'effect'

Tags: looker-studio

An ongoing survey collects data in this structure:

| Have you been diagnosed with ADHD? | What is the your professional field? |
| --- | --- |
| Yes | Science and technology |
| No | Science and technology |
| No | Science and technology |
| Yes | Business, management and administration |
| No | Government |

I currently have these tables, showing the share of each industry among people with diagnosed ADHD vs among people without diagnosed ADHD.

[image]

Which I'd like to combine into one table, showing the *difference* between values.
E.g:

| Profession | ADHD effect |
| --- | --- |
| Science and technology | -4.72% |
| Education | -3.56% |
| Business, management... | 3.63% |

What should the formula be?

After a lot of research I've tried `Sum(if(ADHD diagnose="Yes",1,-1))` Which resulted in this table:

[image]

But this is not the wanted result - I'm not sure how to modify the formula in order to create negative sums as shown in the example.

The data is live and changing so a Looker-Studio-only solution, without the use of a spreadsheet pivot table, is preferred.

[Complete raw data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L64PwN5tIdxHDb-r30R-6uMtA_ucgi4xgh2fWLWXGfo/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please add two fields to your data source `ADHD_yes` as `if(ADHD diagnose="Yes",1,0)` and `ADHD_no.` Under the menu resources, select manage blend and add one. Include the table twice. Left table: no dimension only the both new fields.  Right table: all colums you need as dimension, metrics again the new two fields. Cross join and Save blend. In the graphic add a formula `ADHD_yes (table 2)/ADHD_yes (table 1) - ADHD_no (table 2)/ADHD_no (table 1) `  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70913746/how-can-i-add-a-new-field-in-datastudio-that-refer-to-the-value-in-another-field/70914482#70914482

Comment: note that side effects occur in such automated analyses. Could the sample contain a bias? Could other factors besides diagnosis, such as gender, influence the choice of field of work? More women than men were interviewed and more women have the diagnosis. You need to resample your data to be unique to such factors. Please use a stastistic tool for doing such work.